# Web-scraping with python

Tags: python, html, url, web-scraping, export-to-csv

I want to webscrape https://www.esportsearnings.com/tournaments with a few conditions and then export it to CSV. The conditions are:

1. I want the web scraped text with hyperlinks (`<a href` link)
2. I want to apply a filter while web scraping the data (e.g. scraping data where games = Fortnite)
3. Automate for multiple web pages (e.g. after web scraping 1st page it should automatically scrape 2, 3, 4, etc.)

   ---

   import bs4 as bs
   import urllib.request
   import pandas as pd

   source =     urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.esportsearnings.com/tournaments').read()
   soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
   table = soup.find('table')
   table_rows = table.find_all('tr')

   for tr in table_rows:
   td = tr.find_all('td')
   row = [i.text for i in td]
   print(row)

   ---

I am new to python and not able to complete all the conditions. The above written code just scraps the data. I want to automate it for multiple pages as well as export it to csv.
Can anyone help ?

Comment: And your question is ... ?

Comment: how to automate the code for multiple pages and export it to csv

Answer (score 2):

```
import requests
import xlsxwriter 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('C:/Users/Desktop/data.xlsx') 
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
row = 0
column = 0
linkrow =0

urls = ["https://www.esportsearnings.com/tournaments"] #add more url by adding here
for i in urls:
  page = requests.get(i)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
  i=1
  for link in soup.find_all('a'):
      a=link.get('href')
      worksheet.write(linkrow,0,a)
      print(link.get('href'))
      linkrow += 1
workbook.close()      
# for link in soup.find_all('td'):
#     print(link.get_text())
```

Try this code